# Updating on commit to avoid deadlocks

Tags: sql, oracle, deadlock

I have a table that tracks the last update time of another table's partitions so our reconciler need only check the partitions that have been updated since the last reconcile.  There are multiple threads updating the partitioned table and therefore updating the same row of the latest update time table several times each.  This is obviously causing deadlocks.  Is there a way to prevent these deadlocks by only updating once on commit?

I was thinking of maybe using a session local temporary table, but not sure how to transfer the values to the global table on commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to trigger a process on commit so that approach probably won't work.

Potentially, you could have each of the writer processes write to an Oracle Advanced Queue (AQ) and then have another process that de-queues the messages and actually applies them to the current table.  That would mean that there would be some lag between the writer session committing and the AQ processor picking up and processing the message but that lag shouldn't be too long.  You could do the same thing by having each writer thread insert into a queue-like table and having a separate thread process that table if you don't want to use AQ.

I'm confused, though, by how the process you are describing could cause a deadlock.  Are you really talking about a deadlock (i.e. an ORA-00060 error is thrown and a deadlock trace file is generated)?  What you are describing should lead to blocking locks, not deadlocks, unless there is more going on than you have told us.

Comment: Each of these threads batches writes so that it could be updating 200 different rows per commit.  Since each thread could be updating each row in different orders it results in deadlock.

Comment: @drakkanraz - Why not change the writers so that they update the rows in the tracking table in a particular order at the end of the batch?

Comment: I think that's a good suggestion.  I was trying to do it in the stored procedure to make sure it isn't forgotten about, but it could be done in code after all of the other inserts are done.  Thanks for your help